# davibennun laravel track push notification

Tags: php, ios, git, laravel, notifications

I have done installed APNs in laravel using https://github.com/davibennun/laravel-push-notification and work perfectly on sending push notification to the devices.

And now i can't track if any push notification is failed  ( since using this davibennun library can send push notification to multiple device token and if one of them is failed the rest of notification is not send ).

I have done to search in his github and ask on issues but i dont get any clue, any suggestion ?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:
Since davibennun has merged the pull request from canfiax about new method "getFeedback()" to get feedback from every push notification that already send.

Here following issues and how to use the method.

[#22 issue](https://github.com/davibennun/laravel-push-notification/issues/22)

[how to use getFeedback()](https://github.com/davibennun/laravel-push-notification/pull/27)